# How to Import/Load .csv file in PIG?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata, hadoop-streaming

lets suppose there is a text file tab limited (datetemp.txt) I want to load this text file in pig for processing but when I am typing below line its giving me error as :

grunt> inputfile= load '/training/pig/datetemp.txt' using PigStorage() As (EventID: chararray,eventdate: chararray,count:int);

grunt> dump inputfile;

2014-09-06 08:41:23,527 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2014-09-06 08:41:23,544 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2014-09-06 08:41:23,548 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2014-09-06 08:41:23,548 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2014-09-06 08:41:23,551 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2014-09-06 08:41:23,551 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2014-09-06 08:41:23,552 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - creating jar file Job2739171785773930333.jar
2014-09-06 08:42:39,608 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - jar file Job2739171785773930333.jar created
2014-09-06 08:42:39,612 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2014-09-06 08:42:39,619 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2014-09-06 08:42:39,630 [Thread-12] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient - Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
2014-09-06 08:42:39,891 [Thread-12] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient - Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://192.168.195.130:8020/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/staging/training/.staging/job_201408292336_0009
2014-09-06 08:42:39,891 [Thread-12] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation - PriviledgedActionException as:training (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://192.168.195.130:8020/training/pig/datetemp.txt
2014-09-06 08:42:40,119 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2014-09-06 08:42:40,125 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job null has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2014-09-06 08:42:40,125 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2014-09-06 08:42:40,131 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backend error: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://192.168.195.130:8020/training/pig/datetemp.txt
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:943)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:896)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.startReadyJobs(JobControl.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:260)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://192.168.195.130:8020/training/pig/datetemp.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:231)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextInputFormat.listStatus(PigTextInputFormat.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:248)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:273)
    ... 15 more

2014-09-06 08:42:40,131 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2014-09-06 08:42:40,135 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics:

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.0.0-cdh4.1.1  0.10.0-cdh4.1.1 training    2014-09-06 08:41:23 2014-09-06 08:42:40 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
N/A inputfile   MAP_ONLY    Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://192.168.195.130:8020/training/pig/datetemp.txt
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:943)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:896)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.startReadyJobs(JobControl.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:260)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://192.168.195.130:8020/training/pig/datetemp.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:231)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextInputFormat.listStatus(PigTextInputFormat.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:248)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:273)
    ... 15 more
    hdfs://192.168.195.130:8020/tmp/temp-1004538676/tmp1582688785,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/training/pig/datetemp.txt"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://192.168.195.130:8020/tmp/temp-1004538676/tmp1582688785"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
null

2014-09-06 08:42:40,135 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2014-09-06 08:42:40,142 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias inputfile
Details at logfile: /home/training/pig_1410006833865.log

Please help me here..!!

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 2):

PigStorage is case sensitive. Use PigStorage and not pigstorage.

Comment: @Prix, if my answer has solved your question, please mark it answered.

Comment: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator

Comment: :) thats a different, irrelevant error. You might want to give more details about the error.

Comment: I see the error "Input path does not exist: hdfs://192.168.195.130:8020/training/pig/datetemp.txt". Verify if the file actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your question headliner said you were trying to load a CSV file.  For that, I've had good luck with `using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage()` in my `LOAD` statements as demonstrated at https://martin.atlassian.net/wiki/x/WYBmAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write **PigStorage('\t')** as you have mentioned already you have tab delimited file instead of **PigStorage()**

Mentioned code -

> grunt> inputfile= load '/training/pig/datetemp.txt' using PigStorage()
>   As (EventID: chararray,eventdate: chararray,count:int);

May be this might solve your problem.

let me know if it is something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
hdfs://192.168.195.130:8020/training/pig/datetemp.txt
```

file wat not found in your hdfs!! make sure the input file to be placed in the above location.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether the input path exists?

Try:

`fs -ls /training/pig/ in Grunt Shell`

if it displays datetemp.txt in the list then it will work otherwise give proper input path

Answer (score 0):

Log is telling the ERROR clearly.

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: **ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://192.168.195.130:8020/training/pig/datetemp.txt**

Can you check the file exists in HDFS or not?
You can also check your pig is running in mapreduce mode or local mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify ',' in PigStorage Class to read CSV file.

Query looks like :

```
grunt> inputfile= load '/training/pig/datetemp.txt' using PigStorage(',') As (EventID: chararray,eventdate: chararray,count:int);

grunt> dump inputfile;
```

And make sure that you have file '/training/pig/datetemp.txt' on HDFS.
To test run : `hadoop fs -ls /training/pig/datetemp.txt`